# VSTO 3.0 Excel 2007 Addin Tab doesn't display

Tags: excel, vsto, add-in

This is a very odd problem I've found. I have written and successsfully deployed a VSTO 3.0 Addin for Excel 2007. The problem is that the Tab for the Ribbon only shows up on NEW instances of Excel; the Tab doesn't display if I first open an already existing workbook. However, if I open a new instance of Excel, then open existing workbooks, it'll display.

How can I get the Tab for the Addin to display for both, new instances of Excel and when opening an existing Workbook?

Comment: Are you deploying while running an instance of Excel? Also, Application or Document/Spreadsheet level add-in?

Comment: Excel is not running while deploying. It's an Application-level addin.

Comment: Also, a quick note, the addin is enabled, no errors are showing up and load behavior is set (and stays) at 3.

Comment: Ok you need to clarify the question. As Mike rightly pointed out is Excel running? The reason he asked you this is because in the question you state, that the problem occurs with an existing workbook, but then you use the the term "a new instance of Excel" to describe an a scenario when the problem doesn't occur (implying that you already had Excel.exe open).

to clarify the term existing workbook refers to a file that has already been saved and may be open or closed.
the term an existing Instance of Excel always refers to a Excel.exe process that is running at the time the problem occurs.